# Yellow underline CSS randomly not applied to full width of span

Tags: html, css, background-color, elementor

Example:
https://flowster.app/flowster-affiliate-program-activation-bonus/

You can see that the yellow underline (highlight) only makes it as far as the "A", but it should be underneath "Flowster Affiliate Program":
[image]

However, the HTML looks like this:

```
<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster Affiliate Program</span> -
  Activation Bonus
</h1>
```

And the `yellowhighlight` CSS class looks like:

```
span.yellowhighlight {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

span.yellowhighlight::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.15em;
  right: -0.15em;
  top: 0.8em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #fffa50;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

It's odd because on other pages it looks proper.

```css
span.yellowhighlight {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

span.yellowhighlight::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.15em;
  right: -0.15em;
  top: 0.8em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #fffa50;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster Affiliate Program</span> -
  Activation Bonus
</h1>
```

Comment: add display:inline-block to the span

Comment: @TemaniAfif we're already using these spans in many pages, so that's not a good option.  Hopefully there's a way to update the class CSS?

Comment: How about splitting into three `span` and each `span`  has one word.

Comment: @ЖнецЪ that's not a good long-term solution. This needs to be usable for any text on any page, by non-technical people. Trying to explain to them that they need to use a span for each word will be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use background to achieve this:

```css
span.yellowhighlight {
  --s:0.4em; /* control the size */
  --d:2px;  /* control the distance */
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fffa50 0 0) 50% calc(100% - var(--d))/calc(100% - var(--s)) var(--s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fffa50 98%,#0000) bottom var(--d) left  0/var(--s) var(--s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fffa50 98%,#0000) bottom var(--d) right 0/var(--s) var(--s);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break:clone;
          box-decoration-break:clone;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster Affiliate Program</span> -
  Activation Bonus
</h1>

<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster Affiliate<br> Program</span> -
  Activation Bonus
</h1>
```

To understand the trick use a different coloration for each background layer:

```css
span.yellowhighlight {
  --s:0.4em; /* control the size */
  background:
    linear-gradient(pink 0 0) bottom/calc(100% - var(--s)) var(--s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,blue 98%,#0000) bottom left /var(--s) var(--s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 98%,#0000) bottom right/var(--s) var(--s);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break:clone;
          box-decoration-break:clone;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster Affiliate Program</span> -
  Activation Bonus
</h1>

<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster Affiliate<br> Program</span> -
  Activation Bonus
</h1>
```

Comment: Wow, I think this is the best solution I've seen so far, because it doesn't require any HTML modification, nor do you have to use <span> for every word. Just one thing ... notice how the new yellow highlight is much LOWER than the old one? Can it be moved up so it's more "behind" the words than "underneath" the words? Hopefully that makes sense. I wish it was easy to attach screenshots to comments :(

Comment: @Kane check the update, added another variable to control the distance

Answer (score 3):

## A solution that requires a minimum number of changes to your existing HTML and CSS

After reading all the comments and all the answers, I came up with a solution.

My main goal was not to change any HTML (i.e., same structure, same classes) and not to change the way you want to achieve the underline (i.e., using `::after`). I've tested my solution with Chrome DevTools to be sure that it works.

### Explanation

The trick is, how to achieve a continuous underline when you have three `span` elements (i.e., each word in a separate `span` element).

You need to do just two things:

1. You can achieve a continuous underline with "overflowing". This can be done by setting `width: 120%;`.
2. But you don't want to "overflow" the last `span` element (regardless of how many there are). This can be done by setting `width: 100%;` to the last `span` element.

### Screenshot of my solution IRL

[image: Solution]

### Snippet

```css
span.yellowhighlight {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

span.yellowhighlight::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.15em;
  right: -0.15em;
  top: 0.8em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #fffa50;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 120%; /* Change this. */
}

/* Add this. */
span.yellowhighlight:last-child::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster</span>
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Affiliate</span>
  <span class="yellowhighlight">Program</span>
  - Activation Bonus
</h1>
```

Comment: This looks great, but we need a solution that doesn't require <span> for every word.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the width isn't set. To make the yellow highlight the full width of the text, just add `width: 100%` to `span.yellowhighlight::after`

The final CSS should look like:

```
span.yellowhighlight::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.15em;
  right: -0.15em;
  top: 0.8em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #fffa50;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Edit:

Keeping the CSS same, try to edit the HTML like this

`<span class="yellowhighlight">Flowster </span>Affiliate Program - Activation Bonus`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: See the edited solution

Comment: Why would we only want "Flowster" highlighted? The whole point is to have "Flowster Affiliate Program" highlighted. And no, we don't want some "hack" solution - this needs to work for any text on any page, and be usable by a non-technical person ;)